# Generate random float64 numbers in specific range using Golang

Tags: go, random, floating-point

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func genRandNums(min, max float64) []float64 {
    var randNums []float64
    s := rand.NewSource(time.Now().Unix())
    r := rand.New(s)
    for x := 0; x < 10; x++ {
        // generate random float in range of min and max inclusive, append
        // to randNums and return randNums
    }
    return randNums
}

func main() {
    nums := genRandNums(1.10, 101.98)
    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```

I have tried searching online on how to accomplish this, but I only found out how to generate random integers in a range. Is there any way I can generate random floats in a range using Go stdlib?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Simply use [`rand.Float64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Float64) to get a random number in the range of `[0..1)`, and you can map (project) that to the range of `[min..max)` like this:

```
r := min + rand.Float64() * (max - min)
```

And don't create a new `rand.Rand` and / or `rand.Source` in your function, just create a global one or use the global one of the [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) package. But don't forget to initialize it once.

Here's an example function doing that:

```
func randFloats(min, max float64, n int) []float64 {
    res := make([]float64, n)
    for i := range res {
        res[i] = min + rand.Float64() * (max - min)
    }
    return res
}
```

Using it:

```
func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(randFloats(1.10, 101.98, 5))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8AgpkbSs-3y)):

```
[51.43243344285539 51.92791316776663 45.04754409242326 28.77642913403846
    58.21730813384373]
```

**Some notes:**

- The code on the Go playground will always give the same random numbers (time is fixed, so most likely the Seed will always be the same, also output is cached)
- The above solution is safe for concurrent use, because it uses `rand.Float64()` which uses the global rand which is safe. Should you create your own `rand.Rand` using a source obtained by `rand.NewSource()`, that would not be safe and neither the `randFloats()` using it.

Comment: Not sure it would work for 0...1 range - min + rand.Float64() * (max - min) ==> 0 + rand.Float64() * (1 - 0) --> rand.Float64() * 1 ==> rand.Float64()

Comment: @PARUS It works for `0..1` range too, why wouldn't it? Of course for `0..1` range it's enough to just call and use `rand.Float64()`.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use crypto/rand, here is another go playground for RandomInt() and RandomFloat() generator (float uses RandomInt inside with constant precision - you can make it as parameter)

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RMIHLEdukJR)

Comment: Seems like this solution is a bit hacky - it will generate floats, but they won't be uniformly distributed within the range (due to floatPrecision).

Comment: As I mentioned, if you want to use crypto/rand instead of math/rand, this solution works. Nobody mentined uniform, Gauss or any other distribution. BTW any statistical distribution regarding float64 seems like nonsense to me... You would have a better change to win a lottery before you would generate a second same number with float64 precision ;-)